# Whats the quickest function for keeping time?

Tags: c++-cli

I need to generate a lot of 32bit unix style timestamps for my database. Currently I'm using this:

```
    static UInt32 Now() {
        return (Offset + GetTickCount64()) / 1000;
    }
```

the offset is a precalculated number of milliseconds since year 2000 - tick count at the moment the precalculation took place. Currently I can generate around 20 million timestamps per second per thread with this but it occurred to me that the GetTickCount64 function takes up 80% of the execution time on that. Is there a faster timekeeping function then that?

Comment: Are you sure this is even going to be your bottleneck? You do realize that writing out even just those timestamps to disk is about 76 MB/s of data, which would challenge a goodly number of disk subsystems?

Comment: It likely won't be but.. The database module hides all the book keeping from the front end (including timestamping) and the front end allows for editing macros (which can generate a lot of individual edits very quickly) so in some cases I'd imagine it could be a factor. Also in my case, the changes don't go straight to disk but only when the edits are saved.